# SQL Query : select broken date ranges

Tags: sql, sql-server

Example selecting this date ranges in **ONE QUERY** : `February 1 2013 - February 28, 2013  AND February 1, 2014 - February 28, 2014`

SAMPLE CODE

```
select 
    tenantcode, 
    date 
from DAILY 
where 
    tenantcode = 'CMBINA15' 
    AND date between '02/01/2013' and '02/28/2013' 
    and '02/01/2014' and '02/28/2014'
```

The code does not return any value of course.

Comment: means you want list of dates between given date-range?

Comment: You just need to specify the date range in between. You can use google.

Comment: I cant find an answer after hours of googling, because the query is quite uncommon. Please read the question

Comment: correct answer already was given, should have use OR instead of AND

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Format as `'yyyy-MM-dd'` with `CAST([Mydate] as Date)`

```
select tenantcode, date from DAILY where tenantcode = 'CMBINA15' 
AND CAST([date] as Date) between 
(
CAST('2013-02-01' as DATE) and CAST('2013-28-02'  as DATE) )
OR CAST([date] as Date) between
CAST('2014-02-01' as DATE) and CAST('2014-28-02'  as DATE) )
```

Comment: Thanks also for answering

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
SELECT tenantcode,
       date
FROM   DAILY
WHERE  tenantcode = 'CMBINA15'
       AND ( date BETWEEN '02/01/2013' AND '02/28/2013'
              OR date BETWEEN '02/01/2014' AND '02/28/2014' )
```

Comment: thanks this worked! In my original code, i use AND and by its rule both condition should be true, i forgot to use OR, and it did well, desired output was met, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to use cast or convert function to get proper dateformat of both side. So it will match and give the result.

Or you can use ISDATE function which used when you pass non-date value.

```
select ISDATE('02/01/2013'), CONVERT( varchar(10), @frdate1 , 101)

select tenantcode, date from DAILY where tenantcode = 'CMBINA15' 
AND 
( 
    CONVERT( varchar(10),[date] ,101) between 
        CONVERT( varchar(10), '2013-02-01'  ,101) and CONVERT( varchar(10), '2013-28-02'  ,101) 
    OR 
    CONVERT( varchar(10),[date]  ,101) between
        CONVERT( varchar(10), '2014-02-01' ,101) and CONVERT( varchar(10), '2014-28-02'   ,101) 
)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this, with regards to formatting, there no questions, only want to achieve is for the query to give me a result of broken date range. Thanks